# Paw Version 3.2 New request token not being set in headers

Tags: paw-app

In PAW I have an auth scheme created to generate 2 or 3 legged tokens and set the generated token in the `Authorization` header for each request.

I recently updated PAW to Version 3.2 and it seems that PAW is no longer automatically using the access token generated for my request. Manually generating the token and  clicking `Use Access Token` is also not working. At this point the only thing that is working is to manually generate the token by navigating to the environment management section, opening up my 2 or 3 legged token generation variables, clicking `Get Access token`, highlighting and copying the generated token, pasting that into my header, and replacing `Access Token:` with `Bearer`.

Any direction as to how to get the automatic token generation working again would be much appreciated.

Comment: Downgrading to PAW 3.1.10 has unblocked me

Comment: Exactly same issue. I was wondering what on earth was going on.